# OpenSSL Certificate missing PrivateKey C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, openssl

I got a  code:

```
        string certificateText = File.ReadAllText("./Certificates/cert.pem");
        string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText("./Certificates/key.pem");
        var provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(certificateText, privateKeyText);
        certificate = provider.Certificate;
```

When I checking the private key field, got null value. Also privateKeyText have value on it.
[image]

Comment: You are looking at two different objects.  The Private key in VS starts with a upper case 'P" while the code has a lower case 'p'.

Comment: @jdweng Actually I got 400 error on API, I guess It is because PrivateKey is missing on the certificate. I'm not using PublicKey on my code, It's needed for RestClient

Comment: 400 is a bad request and can be caused because the TLS authentication is failing.  The TLS will fail if the certificate is bad.

Comment: @jdweng already tested on postman, certificates is correct

Comment: If Postman is working then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the TLS version and headers in first request between c# and Postman.  Make the c# look like Postman.  The headers and TLS defaults are not the same in c# and Postman.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by generating p12 certificate

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey "privateKey.pem" -out myProject_keyAndCertBundle.p12
```

then changed my code

```
    public static string userId = "6L29##############################SfkI";
    public static string password = "87t##########GLV";

    public static string cert = "./Certificates/myProject_keyAndCertBundle.p12";
    public static string certificatePassword= "####Password#######";


 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        request.Method = method;
        if (method.Equals("POST") || method.Equals("PUT"))
        {
            // Load the body for the post request
            var requestStringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBodyString);
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(requestStringBytes, 0, requestStringBytes.Length);
        }

        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in headers)
            {
                request.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value;
            }
        }

        // Add headers
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = GetBasicAuthHeader(userId, password);

        // Add certificate
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        try
        {
            // Make the call
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                LogResponse(testInfo, response);
                statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response is HttpWebResponse)
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                LogResponse(testInfo, response);
                statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
        }
        return statusCode;
    }
```